Why does my ASP.NET page return HttpException 0x80004005 for all buttons but one?
I have created a ASP.NET page which populates a table on every page load. The table contains properties for a report and the properties are grouped together.
Every property has a button which is supposed to expand/collapse properties in the group.
To handle which group to toggle expand/collapse I store the group_id in a hidden field when clicking the button.
The first button always works, but other does not...
This is the code from the rendered page:
The hidden field in source code:
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldToggle" Value="" runat="server" />

And the hidden field in web browser:
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$HiddenFieldToggle" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenFieldToggle" value="1">

First button:
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl07" src="../images/Collapse16.png" onclick="return doToggle(1);">

Second button:
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl13" src="../images/Collapse16.png" onclick="return doToggle(2);">

Third button:
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl15" src="../images/Collapse16.png" onclick="return doToggle(3);">

Etc.
And the JavaScript in source code:
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var doToggle = function (id) {
      document.getElementById("<%=HiddenFieldToggle.ClientID%>").value = id;
      return true;
    }
  </script>

And same script from page in browser:
<script type="text/javascript">
    var doToggle = function (id) {
      document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenFieldToggle").value = id;
      return true;
    }
  </script>

Clicking first button always works, other buttons do not.
I can't see why!

You need to debug it to find out which line of C# code the error happens on.

I should have mentioned the error text
Unfortunatelly it's in swedish so I have to translate it:
An error has occured since a control with ID ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl29 couldn't be found.
And debugging only shows that it appears after pageload.


When the page loads, are all the controls definitely always recreated? 2) Also, you might find it easier to use ClientIDMode = "static" so that there is a fixed ID to use in the JavaScript. Docs: Control.ClientIDMode Property.

